# Regex on list of word as input

Tags: python, regex, list

I have sentences in form of list of words, for example

```
sentence = ['if', 'it', 'will', 'rain', ',', 'I', 'will', 'stay', 'at', 'home']
```

Now I would like to find the conditional clause `['if', 'it', 'will', 'rain']`. In principle, I can create a string from the sentence, e.g. `s = ' '.join(sentence)`, I and using regular expressions:

```
p = re.compile(r'(\bif\b[a-zA-z0-9\'\s]+)\s*(,*)\s*(then|,)')
for m in p.finditer(s):
    print m.start(1), m.end(1), '['+s[ m.start(1) : m.end(1) ]+']'
```

no need to judge the regex, it's just a quickly sketched on :). This gives me the output: `0 16 [if it will rain ]`

So far so good. But now I'm kind of missing the connection to my orignal list. The regex gives me character positions and not word/token positions. Ideally, I would get 0 and 3 so I would know that the conditional clause is `sentence[0:3]`. I'm sure I can write a method that maps a character position to the corresponding list index, but I'm sure there's a better to do all this.

Of course, I can ignore regular expression, loop over the list and come up with the right start and stop conditions. But regular currently seem rather neat since they "hide" to make the required conditions explicit. They also simplify the case when the conditional clause is indicated by other words or phrases, e.g.:

```
sentence = ['as', 'long', 'as', 'it', 'will', 'rain', ',', 'I', 'will', 'stay', 'at', 'home']
```

Easy to reflect this with regex, a bit more annoying with using a loop, I assume.

EDIT: Seeing that there's not really a very simple solution, I've went ahead with my idea of creating a mapping between the sentence as a string for the regex and the original word list:

```
def join(self, word_list, separator=' '):
    mapping = []
    string = separator.join(word_list)
    for idx, word in enumerate(word_list):
    for character in word:
        mapping.append(idx)
    for character in separator:
        mapping.append(idx)
    return string, mapping
```

Applying this method to my input `string, mapping = join(sentence)` results in:

```
mapping = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
```

Now, if the regex gives me `0` and `16` as range of the match, I can look up the indexes in the original `sentence` list with `mapping[0] = 0` and `mapping[16] = 4`. So far, this seems to work fairly well. And since I use regex of a string to make the match, I can easily support alternative formulations for the conditional clause, e.g.:

```
CONDITIONAL_PHRASES = ['if', 'as long as', 'even if']
...
p = re.compile(r"((%s)\s+[a-zA-z0-9'\s]+)\s*(then|,)" % '|'.join(CONDITIONAL_PHRASES))
```

Again, I'm not saying that the regex is already perfect, but it supports multiple sentences at once with different indicator words for conditional clauses.

Comment: Depends on how far you want to go, but it seems to me you are half-way into parser territory. So switching to a parser-based solution may give you a more solid base.

Comment: I don't speak python ;) but a quick google makes me wonder if it wouldn't be better to do a `sentence.index(',')` and if that fails `sentence.index('then')`. Otherwise I'd go with the loop like `cond_end_idx = (i for i, item in enumerate(sentence) if match('(then|,)', item))`

Comment: can there be more than one occurence of  `if` and `,` or `then` in your `sentence`?

Comment: to me it's not yet clear what you are looking for. It's clear, that you want to stay close to an array structure. But I don't quite get from your regex what you want to match finally.

Comment: you want impossible :))

Comment: I don't want to deep. I assume simple language with hardly any nested clauses in long sentences. In one sentence I assume only one conditional clause. As I mentioned, the solution with a loop seems to be getting a bit cumbersome if the conditional is indicated by phrase like "as long as" instead of a single word such as "if".

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:-** If there is only one occurrence of `if` and `,` or `then` in `sentence`

I have modified your regex a little bit to include one more capturing group

```
re.compile("((\\bif\\b)[a-zA-z0-9\\'\\s]+)\\s*(,*)\\s*(then|,)")
```

You can use `re.findall` for this as

```
arr = re.findall(p, s)
```

`arr[0][1]` contains the first capturing group (string `if`) and `arr[0][3]` contains the third capturing group (string `then` or `,`). You can use index to find the index of these 2 as

```
start = sentence.index(arr[0][1])
end = sentence.index(arr[0][3])
```

Now, you can form the string using

```
stri = ' '.join(sentence[start: end])
```

**NOTE 1:-** If there are more than one occurrence of `if` and `,` or `then` in `sentence` (non-overlapping), you will have to iterate over all tuples

```
arr = re.findall(p, s)
pos = 0 #It stores the last occurrence of matched group
for i, x in enumerate(arr):
    start = sentence.index(x[1], pos)
    end = sentence.index(x[3], pos)
    stri = ' '.join(sentence[start: end])
    print(stri)
    pos = sentence.index(x[3], pos) + 1
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/998Xgk)**

**NOTE 2:-** Keep in mind that `index` raises an exception if string is not found. Handle it before doing above

Comment: rock, thanks! It looks pretty nice for the "if" but doesn't seem to work with, e.g., `sentence = ['as', 'long', 'as', 'it', 'will', ...]` since the conditional clause is indicated by a phrase and not a single word. Thus, the naive index lookup fails.

Comment: @Christian well I am not very good in English..can you give an example to show how it should work..also tell the possible cases on which you want it to work

Comment: please see my edit of my original question. Given the original example `sentence = ['if', 'it', 'will', ...]` I would like to get `[0, 4]` as result with those values reflecting the start and end of the conditional clause. With `sentence = ['as', 'long', 'as', 'it', 'will', ...]` the result should be `[0, 6]`. With "as long as" instead of "if" your current method won't work properly.

Comment: Yes, as far as the regex is concerned, this works fine and is pretty close to the expression I'm currently using. Using my `mapping` (see EDIT in question), I can now identify the indexes in the input array.

Comment: @Christian so what's next we have to do?

Comment: Nothing, really :). So far, my problems is solved. Testing will tell if the regex needs tweaking, of course. The key issue was to get the correct index positions of the input array. Since the mapping is easy to construct, I will stick with this for now. Rad's solution might work, but it looks prone bugs and might be less easy to modify. Your current solution won't work for `sentence = ['as', 'long', 'as', 'it', 'will', ...]`. You could try to update it, but I would guess it would become quite more complex.

Comment: @Christian i didn't get you..it will work with the updated regex..there will be modification required though due to spaces

Answer (score 1):

Switching to and from a regular expression makes it problematic, because you also have to switch your input to and from a string – and keep them synchronized.

How about a list comparison function in which you have a kind of an OR:

```
sentence = ['if', 'it', 'will', 'rain', ',', 'I', 'will', 'stay', 'at', 'home']
phrase = ['if', [',', 'then']]

def findPhrase(phrase, full):
  currentpos = 0
  isFirst = True
  result = []
  for part in phrase:
    if isinstance(part, list):
      partOffset = 999
      for subpart in part:
        if subpart in full[currentpos:]:
          if full[currentpos:].index(subpart) < partOffset:
            partOffset = full[currentpos:].index(subpart)
      if partOffset == 999:
        return []
      currentpos += partOffset
      if isFirst:
        result.append (currentpos)
      else:
        result[-1] = currentpos
      continue
    if not part in full[currentpos:]:
      return []
    currentpos = currentpos + full[currentpos:].index(part)
    if isFirst:
      result.append (currentpos)
    else:
      result[-1] = currentpos
    # check for a single word match; should still return a range
    # .. just duplicate last item
    if len(result) == 1:
      result.append(result[0])
  return result

res = findPhrase (phrase, sentence)
if res == []:
  print 'not found'
else:
  print res
  print sentence[res[0]:res[1]+1]
```

This compares the 'phrase' against the 'sentence', one word at a time, and returns `[]` if there is no match, and a `start:end` range if there is.

The output of this is

```
[0, 4]
['if', 'it', 'will', 'rain', ',']
```

It is possible to extend the `findPhrase` function with items such as 'optional' and 'any match', but then you'd have to extend the simple array based syntax to something like a dictionary.

Currently, the code skips from one found word to the next, ignoring anything in between. If you want to add an explicit `'*'` 'phrase' item, meaning "skip any number of words", you need to (1) test if it's the *last* item in the match phrase (if so, you can emit the last item of `sentence`), and/or (2) implement a separate lookahead-like function to check if the *next* item in `phrase` is present in `sentence`. (This comes pretty close to mimicking a regex parser.)

Comment: Wow!  It's so ... simple? :/ It may work, but I would take out the word *simple*.  Your function is 31 lines long.

Comment: @zondo: point taken :) I got carried away when adding more and more functionality. The general idea should be clear, though. I failed to shorten the function with list comprehensions or something like that – do you see a way?

Comment: Your `if` checks in `for subpart in part:` could be simplified to `if -1 != full[currentpos].find(subpart) < partOffset:`.  Taking advantage of the fact that for some operators, `x OP1 y OP2 z` is the same as `x OP1 y and y OP2 z`, but without two evaluations of `y`.  It might be a bad idea because it isn't easy to read, but it should be slightly more efficient and it cuts away one line.  Maybe you should try [codereview.se] :)

Comment: Rad, thanks for you efforts! I will give it a try. I wonder, however, if a mapping from character position (regex result) to word position (list index) would not be easier after all.